# Understanding Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, repository

I am trying to understand the generic repository implementation.  I have seen this line (or similar to it) in many examples:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : IEntity
```

Can some explain the parts to this?  Also, I'm having a hard time understanding the IEntity and how it plays into the interface.

```
public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; } 
    } 

public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : IEntity
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
        void Delete(TEntity entity);
        void Add(TEntity entity);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting from the bottom; if you want to know if two values are the same, you just check that they are equal.  Think about 7.  No matter what happens between now and the heat death of the universe, 7 is never going to equal 2.

On the other hand, entities do change.  Today, Bob is 2.  In the due course of time, Bob will be 7.  Even though he isn't 2 any more, he is still Bob.  That's identity, the thing that we use to link different states of history across time.
Put a slightly different way, if we want to know if "Bob" and "the kid in the hat" are the same person, we don't ask their ages, or their names (which could be coincident), we check their identity.

So IEntity is an interface defines an identity.  In sample implementations like this, the actual thing you are modeling (Person) will implement IEntity, and will have some id:int as part of its state.  (A settable id is kind of weird though; the id is usually immutable).

The IRepository interface, now, promises that it can be disposed, and also that the methods that is supports all corresponding to a consistent (but as yet unspecified) type.  However, the type is constrained: this interface for repositories promises that the type is going to be one that implements IEntity.

so you might see

```
class Dog : IEntity {
    ...
}

class Person : IEntity {
    ...
}
```

and matching repositories

```
class DogRepository : IRepository<Dog>
{
    IQueryable<Dog> GetAll();
    void Delete(Dog entity);
    void Add(Dog entity);
}
```

But you aren't going to see, for instance

```
class AgeRepository : IRepository<Age> {
    ...
}
```

Because Age, being a value, isn't going to implement IEntity.

Comment: AgeRepository could recycle instances, but you're right, that would be improper usage of that pattern in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your words.  To verify my assumptions of:     public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : IEntity.  I could say that IRepository inherits IDisposable, and (WHERE) TEntity inherits IEntity?  Is that what the Where keyword does?